# Rails / Javascript - render partial is breaking params check

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a partial that I'm rendering via javascript:

```
$('#calendar').html('<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => "schedules/calendar", :locals => {:schedule_tasks => @schedule_tasks}) %>');
```

and everything works but this one line doesn't work, the params[:day] is in the original URL string:

```
<%= params[:day] == day.to_s ? 'green':'' %>
```

Is there something special I need to do to pass in the params[:day]?  It's still in the URL.

Comment: why not just pass the params within the render locals?

Comment: I have 2 different actions which refresh the partial, so it's getting a bit messy going that route.